# how do simple SQLAlchemy relationships work?

Tags: python, database-design, sqlalchemy

I'm no database expert -- I just know the basics, really. I've picked up SQLAlchemy for a small project, and I'm using the declarative base configuration rather than the "normal" way. This way seems a lot simpler.

However, while setting up my database schema, I realized I don't understand some database relationship concepts.

If I had a many-to-one relationship before, for example, articles by authors (where each article could be written by only a single author), I would put an `author_id` field in my `articles` column. But SQLAlchemy has this ForeignKey object, and a relationship function with a backref kwarg, and I have no idea what any of it MEANS.

I'm scared to find out what a many-to-many relationship with an intermediate table looks like (when I need additional data about each relationship).

Can someone demystify this for me? Right now I'm setting up to allow openID auth for my application. So I've got this:

```
from __init__ import Base
from sqlalchemy.schema import Column
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer, String

class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String, unique=True)
    email = Column(String)
    password = Column(String)
    salt = Column(String)


class OpenID(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'openid'
    url = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    user_id = #?
```

I think the `?` should be replaced by `Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))`, but I'm not sure -- and do I need to put `openids = relationship("OpenID", backref="users")` in the Users class? Why? What does it do? What is a backref?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, you need `user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))` or `user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)` if it's mandatory. This is directly translated to FOREIGN KEY in underlying database schema, no magic.

The simple way to declare relationship is `user = relationship(Users)` in `OpenID` class. You may also use `users = relationship('OpenID')` in `Users` class. `backref` parameter allows you to declare both relationships with single declaration: it means to automatically install backward relationship in related class. I personally prefer using `backref`-s for self-referring relationships only. The reason is that I like self-documented code: when you look through it's definition you see all defined properties, while with `backref` you need to look through other classes (probably defined in other modules).

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I'm kind of surprised it took so long, and nobody else answered... Seems like something lots of people would know about. Oh well :)

Comment: This is a great answer, very clear. I also prefer self-documented code. To that effect, SQLAlchemy, since 0.5.1, provides an alternative to `backref` which is [`back_populates`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.back_populates). The docs present further clarification and an example: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/backref.html#relationships-backref